# Understanding of fork() inside a function

Tags: c, linux, fork

Hi I have a function below in which there is a fork() inside a function. I can simply do the if else one but from incrementing behavior I am unable to understand how to get the output maunally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Call_a_Function(int x, int y)
{
    x++;
    x = fork(); /* #4 */
    if (x)
    {
        x = y;
    }
    else if (fork()) /* #5 */
    {
        x--;
        y += x;
    }
    return x + y;
}
int main()
{
    int x, y = 5, z;
    x = fork(); /* #1 */
    if (x)
    {
        x = y;
        z = Call_a_Function(x, y++);
    }
    else
    {
        (void)fork(); /* #2 */
        z = x++;
        y += z;
    }
    if (y > z)
    {
        (void)fork(); /* #3 */
    }
    printf("%d \n", x + y + z);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is

```
21 6 6 6 16 16 6 14 14
```

But I am unable to get any of these output by manually solving it and making its tree. Please if anyone is able to help me understanding this code.

Comment: The code `x++; x = fork();` makes the increment irrelevant.  Did you really mean to write that?

Comment: For debugging multiple processes, I recommend: (1) capturing the result from each `fork()` call in a variable and (2) print it on `stderr` with a newline at the end. In fact, it is usually good print the PID, the PPID, and the return value from `fork()` each time, along with a tag string that identifies which line of code the output comes from.  Make sure you complete the line of output with a newline (but don't put a space immediately before the newline).  Also, print the integers (`x`, `y`, `z`) at key points — after a sequence of assignments, on function entry, before returning.

Comment: There's not much to ponder here - using fork() in this manner is completely senseless. The main purpose of tasks like this is to keep students busy learning useless crap when they could be studying real programming instead. The only correct use of fork(), if these ever was one, is: `pid_t result = fork(); if(result==0) { noreturn_function_doing_something_specific(); }` Any other use is either disgusting posing/gatekeeping or deliberate obfuscation.

Comment: @Lundin: this is deliberate obfuscation.  It sort of serves a purpose, but not a particularly good one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the problem is to demonstrate that the fork() API is horrible then it fills the purpose. There are easier ways though... some 20 years back at uni, I knocked out not only my station but a whole Solaris computer room with a "fork bomb"... The API remains as horrible now as it was 20 years (and 50 years) back.

Comment: The code should always output the same numbers (as long as the output from each `printf` call does not get intermingled with the output from the other processes), but they could appear in any order depending on when the processes are scheduled.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess the purpose is to practice the skill of running code in your head or on paper to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77143148/understanding-of-fork-inside-a-function#comment135995228_77143148), for debugging multiple processes, I recommend:

1. capturing the result from each fork() call in a variable, and
2. printing it on `stderr` with a newline at the end.

In fact, it is usually good to print the PID, the PPID, and the return value from fork() each time, along with a tag string that identifies which line of code the output comes from. Make sure you complete the line of output with a newline (but don't put a space immediately before the newline). Also, print the integers (x, y, z) at key points — after a sequence of assignments, on function entry, before returning, etc.

This is the instrumented code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int Call_a_Function(int x, int y)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: -->> %s(x = %d, y = %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), __func__, x, y);
    int pid;
    x = fork(); /* #4 */
    if (x != 0)
    {
        x = y;
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --1- %s(x = %d, y = %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), __func__, x, y);
    }
    else if ((pid = fork()) != 0) /* #5 */
    {
        x--;
        y += x;
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --2- %s(pid = %d, x = %d, y = %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), __func__, pid, x, y);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: <<-- %s(return= %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), __func__, x + y);
    return x + y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, y = 5, z;
    fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    x = fork(); /* #1 */
    if (x)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --1- x = %d, y = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x, y);
        x = y;
        z = Call_a_Function(x, y++);
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --2- x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x, y, z);
    }
    else
    {
        int pid = fork(); /* #2 */
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --3- (pid = %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), pid);
        z = x++;
        y += z;
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --4- x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x, y, z);
    }
    if (y > z)
    {
        int pid = fork(); /* #3 */
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --4- (pid = %d)\n", getpid(), getppid(), pid);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: --4- x = %d, y = %d, z = %d; sum = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x, y, z, x + y + z);
    printf("%d\n", x + y + z);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "PID = %5d, PPID = %5d: child %5d exited 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), getppid(), corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run that code, one of the outputs was:

```
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: --1- x = 52964, y = 5
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: -->> Call_a_Function(x = 5, y = 5)
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: --1- Call_a_Function(x = 5, y = 5)
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: <<-- Call_a_Function(return= 10)
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: --2- x = 5, y = 6, z = 10
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: --4- x = 5, y = 6, z = 10; sum = 21
21
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: --3- (pid = 52966)
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0
PID = 52966, PPID = 52964: --3- (pid = 0)
PID = 52966, PPID = 52964: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: --2- Call_a_Function(pid = 52967, x = -1, y = 4)
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: <<-- Call_a_Function(return= 3)
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: --2- x = 5, y = 6, z = 3
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: --4- (pid = 52968)
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0; sum = 6
6
PID = 52967, PPID = 52965: <<-- Call_a_Function(return= 5)
PID = 52967, PPID = 52965: --2- x = 5, y = 6, z = 5
PID = 52966, PPID = 52964: --4- (pid = 52969)
PID = 52968, PPID = 52964: --4- (pid = 0)
PID = 52966, PPID = 52964: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0; sum = 6
PID = 52968, PPID = 52964: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0; sum = 6
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: --4- (pid = 52970)
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: --4- x = 5, y = 6, z = 3; sum = 14
6
6
14
PID = 52967, PPID = 52965: --4- (pid = 52971)
PID = 52967, PPID = 52965: --4- x = 5, y = 6, z = 5; sum = 16
16
PID = 52970, PPID = 52965: --4- (pid = 0)
PID = 52970, PPID = 52965: --4- x = 5, y = 6, z = 3; sum = 14
PID = 52969, PPID = 52966: --4- (pid = 0)
14
PID = 52969, PPID = 52966: --4- x = 1, y = 5, z = 0; sum = 6
6
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: child 52968 exited 0x0000
PID = 52971, PPID = 52967: --4- (pid = 0)
PID = 52971, PPID = 52967: --4- x = 5, y = 6, z = 5; sum = 16
16
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: child 52970 exited 0x0000
PID = 52966, PPID = 52964: child 52969 exited 0x0000
PID = 52967, PPID = 52965: child 52971 exited 0x0000
PID = 52965, PPID = 52963: child 52967 exited 0x0000
PID = 52964, PPID = 52963: child 52966 exited 0x0000
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: child 52965 exited 0x0000
PID = 52963, PPID =  2740: child 52964 exited 0x0000
```

With that information, you can deduce what goes on.  There are 9 processes in total to keep track of — it doesn't make it easy, but it is also why it is helpful (I was tempted to say "crucial") to identify where the outputs are coming from.

When I run the code like this (program name: `fork23`):

```
$ fork23 2>/dev/null
21
6
6
6
14
6
14
16
16
$
```

The sequence of output numbers is not determinate — the o/s may schedule the processes differently on different runs.  However, the nine values printed should always be 1 x 21, 2 x 16, 2 x 14, 4 x 6.